# Extracting SQL out from Crystal Report files

Tags: c#, sql, .net, crystal-reports

I'm trying to extract the select SQL from Crystal Report's `.rpt` files using C#.net. By that, I'm referring to the SQL that you will see when you go under `Database > Show SQL Query` in the menu in Crystal Report. I've followed the solution from [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706128/i-would-like-to-extract-the-sql-queries-from-crystal-report-rpt-files-is-there), but it seems like I'm not getting the same result. I'm using this set of code:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("c:\\projects\\Reports", "*.rpt"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Processing {0}...", file));
    var doc = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
    doc.Load(file);

    foreach (dynamic table in doc.ReportClientDocument.DatabaseController.Database.Tables)
    {
        if (table.ClassName == "CrystalReports.CommandTable")
        {
            //I will never reach here because table.ClassName is CrystalReports.Table
            string commandSql = table.CommandText;

            //TODO: do something with commandSql
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, the dynamic `table` variable in the `foreach` loop are all of `CrystalReports.Table` type instead of `CrystalReports.CommandTable` type. And so, I don't have access the `CommandText` property.

The closest with the `Table` type is I could get the table names in the SQL in the report, but not the selected columns.

How can I extract the columns and tables of the respective columns of the SQL in a Crystal Report file?

I'm using the Crystal Report .NET SDK 13.0.9 for Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because the report file contains a DataSet as a source and not an embedded SQL query.

I tested the code with 2 report files, a file with embedded SQL query and a file linked to a DataSet.

The below images show the QuickWatch window content for the variable `table` after the `ClassName` comparison is made.

---

Report containing an SQL query as a source

[image]

shows `ClassName = "CrystalReports.CommandTable"`

---

Report containing a DataSet as a source

[image]

shows `ClassName = "CrystalReports.Table"`

---

Comment: oh thanks for highlighting this! I'm new to Crystal Reports and so I didn't know about this. In this case, are there still other ways I can extract that SQL from either the dataset or the embedded query?

Comment: If the report contains an embedded query, you can retrieve it by using the code that you already have. In the case of a DataSet you can't do much because the data will be sent to the report on runtime. So a DataSet doesn't contain any embedded query but it's just a placeholder for some fields. Check [this article](http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_without_database.htm) for more information about a report containing a DataSet.

Comment: Since I was able to review the `select` SQL when I go under Database > Show Query menu, does this imply that the report is using embedded query? Or it could also be using DataSet?

Comment: A report can use multiple sources (SQL query, DataSet etc) at the same time but since you was able to see the query that means that the report contains at least an embedded SQL query.

Comment: Then this is really weird because in those reports that I am getting `CrystalReports.Table`, I can actually see the SQL query from the "Show Query" menu. So they have an embedded SQL in it, but the API can't return them as type CommandTable?